# While loop counter increasing "exponentially" in spite of using ++

Tags: javascript, while-loop, counter, nested-function

**Background information**

I am setting up a function which creates a date array based on a start date and an end date.

The function will receive start and end dates, which have first been formatted to `year-month-dayT12:00:00:00` format and then converted into milliseconds with `.getTime()` format.

**My script**

I have made the following script to create the array.

```
var $date_array = [];

function calc_workdays_between_dates (a, b) {

    function $create_date_array ($start_date, $end_date) {

        var $counter    = 0;

        while ($start_date !== $end_date) {

            var x = new Date($start_date);

            x.setDate(x.getDate() + $counter);
            $date_array.push(x);
            $start_date = x.getTime();
            $counter++; 
        }
    }

    $create_date_array (a, b);
}
```

Please be aware that there is a reason for nesting the `$create_date_array` function inside the `$calc_workdays_between_dates` function. For now I have stripped out all other parts of the `$calc_workdays_between_dates` function to focus solely on the problem at hand (I am also running my tests on this stripped down version - so the rest of the function is not there to affect anything).

**My problem**

*Example 1:*

If I invoke the function with `calc_workdays_between_dates (x1, x2);` where:

```
x1 = new Date("2015-04-04") //formatted and converted to ms before invoking function
x2 = new Date("2015-04-07")
```

it results in `$date_array` getting the following content:

```
Sat Apr 04 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sun Apr 05 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 07 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

As you can see the function for some reason skips monday (one day in total).

*Example 2:*

```
x1 = new Date("2015-04-04") //formatted and converted to ms before invoking function
x2 = new Date("2015-04-10")
```

results in:

```
Sat Apr 04 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sun Apr 05 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 07 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

As you can see the function somehow skips Monday, Wednesday and Thursday (3 days in total).

*Example 3:*

```
x1 = new Date("2015-04-04") //formatted and converted to ms before invoking function
x2 = new Date("2015-04-14")
```

results in:

```
Sat Apr 04 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Sun Apr 05 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 07 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Fri Apr 10 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
Tue Apr 14 2015 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

As you can see the function in thise instance skips Monday, Wednesday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday and Monday (6 days in total).

*Example 4:*

```
x1 = new Date("2015-04-04") //formatted and converted to ms before invoking function
x2 = new Date("2015-04-08")
```

results in the function not working. It appears that the while loop continues to run endlessly.

**My question**

What is making the script skip days?

Comment: Ehm, your `$create_date_array` func expects a `Date` object, but you are passing an array (`x1 = [new Date("2015-04-04")]`). Am I missing something?

Comment: @NikolaDimitroff: The `$create_date_array` function receives the dates in milliseconds which is then converted to a date my the function itself before performing any calculation. It was another error that the dates appear in brackets. I have deleted them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You calculate the next date based on `$start_date` and `counter`. However, in the while-loop `$start_date` is reassigned and thus not represent the start date anymore. Therefore it should not be incremented with `counter`, but only with one.

A correct solution would be:

```
while ($start_date !== $end_date) {
    var x = new Date($start_date);
    x.setDate(x.getDate() + 1);
    $date_array.push(x);
    $start_date = x.getTime();
}
```

Comment: Oh my god - thank you @mvdssel. My head is aching from staring at the script for about 90 minutes by now. I just could not see it! Thank you so much!